# generating all IP address between two IP addresses in java

Tags: java, split, ip-address

I am trying to get all the IP addresses between the two addresses("168.200.197.3" and "238.199.200.78"). I splited the string to integer first. Then i tried to printout all addresses between these two. But the output only shows that each part of the address is being incremented, like 168 169 170......  I want the whole address to be increased(168.200.197.3, 168.200.197.4,168.200.197.5....etc). Please help !!!!!!!

```
public class IpAddress {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] ip1 = new int[4];
    int [] ip2 = new int[4];

    String [] parts1 = "168.200.197.3".split("\\.");
    String [] parts2 = "238.199.200.78".split("\\.");

    for (int i = 0; i <4; i++){
        ip1[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts1[i]);   
              for (int j = 0; j<4; j ++){
                    ip2[j] = Integer.parseInt(parts2[j]);
                           for (int k = ip1[i]; k<ip2[j]; k++){
                                  System.out.println(k);
                                        }
                                 }  
                        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An IPv4 address like `a.b.c.d` can be represented by an unsigned integer `a*256^3+b*256^2+c*256+d`. Now you can turn the two IP addresses into unsigned integers then you get an integer range, iterate the range and convert each unsigned integer back to IPv4 literal.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Interesting to say that is more appropriate to create the ipFromInt as "rolfl" user does it, rather than using divisions and observing the rest, because anything is faster than divisions.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me I would do this using an `int` value to represent the IP address and write a function that converts the `int` to a String representation of the IP:

```
private static final String getIPFromInt(final long ipaslong) {
    return String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
                (ipaslong >>> 24) & 0xff,
                (ipaslong >>> 16) & 0xff,
                (ipaslong >>>  8) & 0xff,
                (ipaslong       ) & 0xff);
}
```

Then I would calculate the start and end points by converting them to int representations (the opposite problem as the getIPFromLong(...) method, which I will leave as an exercise for you) and finally I would write a simple loop:

```
final long from = getLongFromIP(ip1);
final long to = getLongFromIP(ip2);

for (long i = from; i <= to, i++) {
    System.out.println(getIPFromLong(i);
}
```

EDIT: Changed loop argument `i` to be a long, and the other methods to accept `long` instead of `int` to avoid issues with integer sign bits.

Comment: thank you so much!!! in your getIPFromInt method, i tried to use some larger addresses like 176.130.250.76, it returns me a negative number :-1333593524. Do you you why this happens?

Comment: Yes, Java `int` is a signed value. Any IP adress above 128.0.0.0 will be represented as anegative number. which makes me realize that my code has a bug.... and was not all that helpful. Change all 'int' values to 'long' and you will not encounter this issue (unless you use IPv6)